# How to implement the concept of cellular automata in python

Tags: python

I am fairly new at python (and programming in general, just started 2 months ago). I have been tasked with creating a program that takes a users starting string (i.e. "11001100") and prints each generation based off a set of rules. It then stops when it repeats the users starting string. However, I am clueless as to where to even begin. I vaguely understand the concept of cellular automata and therefore am at a loss as to how to implement it into a script.

Ideally, it would take the users input string "11001100" (gen0) and looks at the rule set I created and converts it so "11001100" would be "00110011" (gen1) and then converts it again to (gen3) and again to (gen4) until it is back to the original input the user provided (gen0). My rule set is below:

```
print("What is your starting string?")

SS = input()
gen = [SS]
while 1:
    for i in range(len(SS)):
        if gen[-1] in gen[:-2]:
            break
    for g in gen:
        print(g)


newstate = {
    #this is used to convert the string. we break up the users string into threes. i.e if user enters 11001100, we start with the left most digit "1" and look at its neighbors (x-1 and x+1) or in this case "0" and "1". Using these three numbers we compare it to the chart below:
    '000': 1 ,
    '001': 1 ,
    '010': 0 ,
    '011': 0 ,
    '100': 1 ,
    '101': 1 ,
    '110': 0 ,
    '111': 0 ,
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help or further explanation/dummy proof explanation of how to get this working.

Comment: please fix your formatting and indentation, this code is currently unclear as to what you are trying to achieve. trick tip, copy and past your code then highlight it all and press `ctrl+k`

Comment: Sorry about that. I am still new to this. I removed my code and just explained in words what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: It is better for you to post code of what you have tried (just make sure it is formatted properly) so we can help you and show you where you have gone wrong and fix it. SO is not a code-writing service

Comment: The code I have tried is not technically code that has been "tried". I do NOT know how to implement what is being asked of me fully. I have more of a basic structure built based on what I currently know at this point in my learning of Python.

Comment: I have re-added my basic structured building block (best way to put it really) of what I think is being asked of me. I really do not know where to go from here and I was not given a lecture over any of this material. I was simply handed a piece of paper and told "here code this"...for a 100 level course in college, whose emphasis is on students with "no prior coding experience of any kind" this is a bit out of my grasp to complete.

Comment: you have two `input` calls, what do you expect in the first one? I assume the second one is looking for something like `11001100` but correct me if im wrong

Comment: Also, if I am not asking the right question or if what I am asking cannot be answered here, I would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction of where to find an answer to what I am asking as opposed to just saying "SO is not a code-writing service."

Comment: HAHA, whoops, that first input should not be there anymore >.> you are correct that my second input is looking for "11001100"

Comment: look at regex operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `newstate` is a valid dict where the key/value pairs correspond with your state replacement (if you want `100` to convert to `011`, `newstate` would have `newstate['100'] == '011'`), you can do list comprehensions on split strings:

```
changed = ''.join(newstate[c] for c in prev)
```

where `prev` is your previous state string. IE:

```
>>> newstate = {'1':'0','0':'1'}
>>> ''.join(newstate[c] for c in '0100101')
'1011010'
```

you can then use this list comp to change a string itself by calling itself in the list comprehension:

```
>>> changed = '1010101'
>>> changed = ''.join(newstate[c] for c in changed)
>>> changed
'0101010'
```

you have the basic flow down in your original code, you jsut need to refine it. The psuedo code would look something like:

```
newstate = dict with key\value mapping pairs
original = input

changed = original->after changing

while changed != original:
    changed = changed->after changing

print changed
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be with the re.sub() method in the python regex module, re.

```
    import re

def replace_rule(string, new, pattern):
    return re.sub(pattern, new, string)

def replace_example(string):
    pattern = r"100"
    replace_with = "1"
    return re.sub(pattern, replace_with, string)

   replace_example("1009")
=> '19'
   replace_example("1009100")
=> '191'
```

Regex is a way to match strings to certain regular patterns, and do certain operations on them, like sub, which finds and replaces patterns in strings. Here is a link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: I had no idea Python had regex! I have just a little experience with regex (from what I have learned in Perl so far). I will fiddle around with regex in Python and try to implement what I know.